# Windows Phone - Accessing DataContext takes up to 4 Seconds

Tags: windows-phone-7, datacontext

im currently creating a application for windows phone.
Well on the "main page" you'll have a barely overview over your
"Characters".

All your Characters are stored in an Singleton Configuration Class.

To generate the Overview i simple use a ListBox, with a Datatemplate, like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox_Characters" Margin="0,0,-12,0"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Config},Path=Instance.Characters}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Button Style="{StaticResource CharacterButton}" Click="Button_Click_2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
          <Image Source="{Binding ShowPortrait}" Height="110" Width="110" Margin="0,15,0,0" />
          <StackPanel Width="311">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShowCurrentlyTraining}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
            <ProgressBar Value="{Binding CurrentlyTrainingPercentage}" IsIndeterminate="{Binding CurrentlyUpdating}" />
            <Grid>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShowSPs}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
              <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ShowCurrentlyTrainingPercentage}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShowWealth}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
      </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now i've added a Page, to show more details. The page should be reachable by clicking one of the Characters from the ListBox above.

To know "what" Character is selected, i tried to simple store the characterID in the Singleton Class, and then load the appropriate character from the Detail Page.

unfortunately i don't get the point: 
This is the "Click" Method, with already added a time measurement.
The message Box finally tells me: "Clicking Method takes 3.896"

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //stop the update timer
            Configuration.Instance.updater.Stop();

            //Get current character id
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now; //time measurement

            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            Character myChar = (Character)btn.DataContext;
            Configuration.Instance.CharacterToReload = myChar.CharacterID;

            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(start); //time measurement
            MessageBox.Show("Clicking method takes " + ts.TotalSeconds); //time measurement

            //Navigate to Detail Page
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Details.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

How can these simple "casts" take upto 3 seconds?
Did i miss something?

best regards,
dognose

edit: Why i'm always working some hours without success - and then, right after creating a post in the boards, i figured it out?

I've added a Save Method for the IsolatedStore in the "set" part of the property "CharacterToReload" - which takes arround 4 seconds (lot of data / pictures )

Comment: What's the structure of `Character`? Can you recreate this with a simpler model? (Try using the default code in a DataBound Application.)

Answer (score 0):

My guesss is that the setter for the Configuration.CharacterToReload is where the time is being taken.

I would suggest that you set the CharacterId as a query Parameter in the Navigate Uri - this will facilitate re-hydrating your app if the user closes it when navigated to the details page.

In your Navigated override in your detail page, get the query parameter from the Navigation context to set the detail page data context.

```
var uriString = string.Format("/DetailPage.xaml?character={0}", characterId);
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uriString, UriKind.Relative));
```

**DetailPage**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string characterId;

    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("character", out characterId))
    {
        int index = 0;

        if (int.TryParse(charaterId, out index))
        {
           // set data context of detail page.
        }
    }
}
```